# How does bundler --deployment handle native extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, bundler

I understand the advantages of `bundler install --deployment`, that the gems are taken from my copy and not installed live.

But what about native extensions, which require per-OS compilation? How can I use `install --deployment` if I develop on one OS and deploy on another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will build the native extensions when run on the production server.  So long as the dependencies are available (external libraries or whatever building the gem requires), it'll all work as expected.

Note that the gems **are** installed; they're just installed in `vendor/bundle` by default with `--deployment`, rather than installed system-wide.  All the normal things that `gem install` does will happen, but the default installation path is under `vendor/bundle`.  You can override that, too, with `--path`, if you really need to.  If you want them installed system-wide, you can do `bundle install --local` to read them out of `vendor/cache` and install them system-wide.